# Why can't I delete Tomcat6 service?

Tags: tomcat

I'm completely befuddled. 
Windows 7 Professional w/ Service Pack 1, 64 bit.

I'm trying to Install Apache Tomcat 7, but Tomcat 6 was previously installed. It may not have been installed correctly, I'm not sure.

I downloaded apache-tomcat-6.0.44-windows-x64.zip and moved it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin.

Set environment variable CATALINA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0

I navigated to the tomcat 6 directory and attempted to remove as described in related contributions:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin>service.bat remove
Removing the service 'Tomcat6' ...
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0"
The specified service has been marked for deletion.
Unable to delete 'Tomcat6' service
The specified service has been marked for deletion.
Failed to delete service
Failed removing 'Tomcat6' service
```

So... I can't delete the service, because its been marked for deletion. WHA.....?????

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I needed to remove references to Tomcat6 from the registry and reboot. What a PITA!

Ref: [source](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1584409?start=45&tstart=0)